# When are you supposed to declare types with mypy?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I'm new to working with mypy and am trying to figure out when you should declare types.

For instance, I ran this code snippet after running:

`pip install mypy pandas data-science-types`

N.B. I used the `data-science-types` [library](https://github.com/predictive-analytics-lab/data-science-types) to get type hints for `pandas`; it's not actively maintained but seems to work fine on simple tests like the one I'm doing here.

```
import pandas as pd

df: pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3]})

# mypy is fine with this
df["b"] = "testing"
# mypy is not fine with this
df["b"]: pd.Series = "testing"
# mypy is fine with this
x: pd.Series = df["b"]
```

This gives the following output:

```
myscript.py:8: error: Unexpected type declaration
```

Line 8 refers to the line `df["b"]: pd.Series = "testing"`. It seems I'm doing something wrong there but I'm not 100% sure what.

Do I only declare a type when creating a new variable? If so, anybody know what's the rationale behind that?

EDIT: While I understand type annotations are optional, they are helpful for type checking which I need to implement on some projects. So that's the context for why I'm trying to figure this out.

Comment: Adding type annotations is entirely optional. It's supposed to help you document your code and spot mistakes early. Use them whenever it is convenient.

Comment: I'm not sure if your real question is about the error you are getting.

Comment: Thanks @mkrieger1 , do you mean like I more need to figure out where it's useful for me to type check rather than try to understand some syntactic rule about type checking that doesn't actually exist?

Answer (score -1):

you are declaring that the type of the element will be `pd.Series` but since the type is a string you are getting an error

if you like you can do like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df: pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3]})
df["b"] = "testing"
#declaring it as a string
df["b"]: str = "testing"
x: pd.Series = df["b"]
```

but the type annotations are completely unnaccessary, as it said in the comment

> Adding type annotations is entirely optional. It's supposed to help you document your code and spot mistakes early.

so in reality you can simplify the code to look like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3]})

df["b"] = "testing"
df["b"] = "testing" #this line is unnecessary

x = df["b"]
```

Comment: Declaring it as a string throws the same error for me, does it not for you?

Comment: for me it works just fine, output:[link](https://imgur.com/a/nyPKIOZ)